# How to add pagination in SheetJS Sheet_to_html

Tags: html, angular, sheetjs

I am using sheetjs https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs for reading xlsx file and converting it into html for preview. For big excel files the browser get busy and consume lots of memory. Is there any way to overcome this issue, I am thinking to apply pagination.

Angular Component:

```
createHtmlTable(workBook: WorkBook) {
    this.sheetName = workBook.SheetNames[0];
    let generatedTableHtml: any = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_html(workBook.Sheets[workBook.SheetNames[0]],
      { id: 'DataTableDiv'/*, editable: true, */});
    
    generatedTableHtml = generatedTableHtml.replace('<table',
      '<table mat-table border="1"')
      .replaceAll('<tr>', '<tr><td></td>');

    const tableElement = document.getElementById('DataTableDiv');
    tableElement.innerHTML = generatedTableHtml;

  }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="DataTableDiv"></div>
```